# no puedo programar en vpython

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Estoy queriendo instalar VPython 7 para python 3.x, en la pagina de vpython explica como instalar, pero para una version antigua de python, la version 2.7. Las instrucciones son:
descargar python 2.7, descargar vpython 6, instalar ambos y ya esta.

Para python 3.x es mas complicado, dice que tengo que instalar anaconda, lo cual evita que tenga que descargar python ya que este lo trae incorporado. Luego me dice que desde el prompt de anaconda instale vpython, y luego instale un archivo de node.js o algo asi.
Todos estos ultimos pasos ya lo hice, y hay cosas que no termino de entender:

1. anaconda instala python lo cual evita que tenga que descargarlo aparte, esto lo compruebo en el CMD y efectivamente, puedo programar en python, sin embargo, cualquier archivo extension .py, windows lo muestra sin icono e incluso no sabe como abrirlo
2. al parecer, al instalar anaconda con su python integrado, no puedo o no se como programar en VScode aunque en anaconda me aparece VScode
3. la unica forma que encontre (con lo poco que se) de programar python es en jupyterlab, aunque no se como empezar a programar vpython alli

agradeceria mucho la ayuda con este tema de vpython, anaconda, vscode, etc. ya que en internet no encuentro mucha informacion, o es algo compleja.

me gustaria mucho poder programar vpython en vscode y no en otro editor, asi que si hay alguna forma de hacerlo, me encantaria saberlo

Comment: Has probado pip install vpython o pip install vpython==7.5.0 ?

Comment: Hice otra pregunta, acerca de jupyterlab, ahí trate de instalarlo con: jupyter labextension instaló vpython,  pero me salta un error

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda es un distribución libre y abierta​ de los lenguajes `Python` y `R`.

Cuando instalas Anaconda, al lado izquierdo de la ventana principal está el panel con las opciones`Home`(Ventana principal), `Environments`(Entornos) y otros más.

Si vas a Entornos, podrás ver esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí podrás crear un nuevo entorno donde descargarás e instalarás todos los paquetes que quieras.

Vpython es uno de ellos. Aquí se indica como instalarlo.

https://anaconda.org/vpython/vpython

Es básicamente abrir el entorno creado en la terminal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ejecutar unos cuantos comandos, luego podrás llamar el paquete desde el código y utilizarlo según lo necesites.